# Loop to select which variable to omit from analysis

Tags: spss

I have datasets with a large number of variables and I need to run PCA over these datasets with one variable removed each time. Below are 20 variables for an example dataset. I would like to run PCA with one variable removed from each PCA solution. For example, the first PCA solution will include all variables excluding Var_1_GroupA, the second will include all variables excluding  Var_2_GroupA, etc. I am familiar with using macros to write loops but unsure how to complete the following task using macros or code in python.

```
Var_1_GroupA 
Var_2_GroupA 
Var_1_GroupB 
Var_2_GroupB 
Var_3_GroupB 
Var_1_GroupC 
Var_2_GroupC 
Var_3_GroupC 
Var_4_GroupC 
Var_5_GroupC 
Var_1_GroupD 
Var_1_GroupE 
new_Var_1_GroupA 
new_Var_1_GroupB 
new_Var_1_GroupC 
new_Var_2_GroupC 
Var_1_GroupF 
Var_1_GroupG 
Var_1_GroupH 
Var_2_GroupH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below I create 10 variables, and then run a simple `means` command with a different set of variables each time - excluding one of the variables at a time. You can edit the code to match your variables and your analysis code.

```
data list list/var1 to var10 (10F1).
begin data
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9
    5 4 3 6 3 8 1 2 5 8
    0 8 6 4 2 1 3 5 7 9
end data.
dataset name wrk.

define !loopit (!pos=!cmdend)
!do !a !in(!1)
    means 
    !do !b !in(!1) !if (!b<>!a) !then !b !ifend !doend 
    .
!doend
!enddefine.

!loopit var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10 .
```

note you vave to list the variable names in the macro call, can't use `var1 to var10`.

If you run into trouble while adapting this to your exact needs, these are very helpful in debugging macros:

```
set mexpand=on.
set mprint=on.
```

Comment: Hi Eli-K, thanks a lot for this. Just to confirm that the solution below is valid. Rather than explicitly naming each variable in !loopit, I could use spssinc select variables to create a variables list based on a regular expression (using the following):      spssinc select variables macroname="!Vars_List" /properties pattern=".*Var".       Then call the list using the following: 
      !loopit !Vars_List .

Comment: I've read that `spssinc select variables` can only be used for Python access, so just wanted to make sure that it can be used as lists to feed into SPSS Macros. I want to make sure that this is a valid thing to do before integrating it into my workflow https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006PFpHK/create-new-variables-based-on-a-macro-var-set?language=en_US

Comment: Yes, you can use `spssinc select variables` to create your list instead of naming each variable. BTW if they don't all share a specific pattern or attribute, you can create more then one list and go `!loopit !Vars_List1 !Vars_List2 .` .

Comment: As for your other question - Yes -  `spssinc select variables` relies on Python programming and will not work without access to Python. If you have a reasonably updated version of SPSS you probably have access to Python without any additional installations. BUT - if you have a problem with access to Python, there are other ways to automate creation of your variable list [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881681/systematically-renaming-variables-in-spss-without-python) can put you on the right path (or start a new question).